# Would like to filter by [tag:java] OR [tag:android] - (not AND!)

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-filters

I find my self jumping between those the tags Java and Android very often while looking for new questions.

I know that I can filter by `tag1` AND `tag2` like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+java

That has the disadvantage that I do not get the [java](/questions/tagged/java) questions that have nothing to do with [android](/questions/tagged/android), but I am also very interested in those.

So I would like to do it filter by `tag1` OR `tag2` to also get the pure java + pure android questions!

For the case something like this is already possible, please kindly explain how it should be done. I tried to find such an OR filter but could not find it and at least for me would be very useful! Thx!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+or+java

Comment: @IlmariKaronen Thx! Exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

Ok this is resolved! I just didn't find the OR operator myself:

stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android+or+java

Thx!